# RSA encryption using public key. Data size based on key

Tags: c++, openssl, size, rsa

I'm using the OpenSSL RSA API to encrypt data with a server's public key.

```
uint32_t rsasize = RSA_size(keypair); // -- RSA key size == 256

uint32_t dl = 255
uint8_t *d; // points to 255 bytes of data

unsigned char *encrypt = (unsigned char*)malloc(rsasize);

auto num = RSA_public_encrypt(dl, d, encrypt, keypair, RSA_NO_PADDING);
if ( num == -1 )
{
    auto err = malloc(130);
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), (char*)err);
    printf("Error encrypting message: %s\n", err);
    return nullptr;
}
```

I'm using `RSA_NO_PADDING` so RSA should crypt 255 bytes with 256 byte public key easily. But I'm receiving this:

```
Error encrypting message: error:0406B07A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_none:data too small for key size
```

I changed dl(data_lenght) to 256 (just +1) and I got this:

```
Error encrypting message: error:04068084:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_ENCRYPT:data too large for modulus
```

I know that RSA can encode 255 bytes with 256-key. What's the problem?

Comment: You probably want to use padding. But if you don't use padding, you muse have `dl==rsasize`. I would verify that `rsasize` is what you think it is for your pair.

Comment: I cannot use padding, since I want to encode 255 bytes with 256 key. Padding will add restriction on max lenght of data (it will work only with dl <= 245 bytes, I just don't remember padding size). If I use dl==rsasize (256) I receive rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PUBLIC_ENCRYPT:data too large for modulus. Modulus == 256, according to RSA_size(keypair)

Comment: From [`RSA_size`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/RSA_size.html): *"RSA_size() returns the RSA modulus size in bytes. It can be used to determine how much memory must be allocated for an RSA encrypted value."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are padding at the wrong end. If you have 255 bytes of data and you want to pad it out to 256 you should add a zero byte *at the high-order end*. In other words, you should insert a 0 just before d[0].

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use paddings, I have exactly 255 bytes of data. I was trying to add one extra byte, to have 256 (equal to key size), but it returns different error (see my post).

Comment: You have ignored what I wrote. "adding one extra" byte is padding. You just need to do it on the other side.

Comment: You did the same. I've tried that already. OpenSSL says "data too large for modulus". For any 256 (255+1) bytes data

Comment: That message is impossible if the high-order data byte is zero.